# Changing the yellow focus in Listview when its scrolling ends?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-theme

Can we change default yellow focus that will appear when `ListView` items end while scrolling. I want to change that focus color to some blue. How to achieve this? Thanks In Advance.

[image]

Edit:

seems there are

```
public void setOverscrollFooter (Drawable footer)
```

and

```
public void setOverscrollHeader (Drawable header)
```

from API levl 9. But still no luck with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in XML File.

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

Comment: I want change focus color.

Comment: It's depend on Device theme. we can't change that @vrs

Comment: @vrs, Mehul is right, this is device theme specific. On my SGS2 is is blue.

Comment: @Mehul Patel I think you are right.what you are saying is, we can't override that theme at app level, we can only stop that focus by setting android:overScrollMode="never", correct me If I wrong.